# How to assigning BaseController values from unit test in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

We are trying to add unit test in our existing MVC application. Our all controllers inherits a `BaseController` which is given below:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public virtual Tenant Tenant
    {
        get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["Tenant"] as Tenant; }
    }
}
```

Now, here's a sample controller inherits `BaseController` and works very well:

```
public class DefaultController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // TODO: repository calls
        return View();
    }
}
```

But as soon as I add `string tenantid = Tenant.Id;` in above controller (given below), my unit test fails.

```
public class DefaultController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // TODO: repository calls
        string tenantid = Tenant.Id;
        return View();
    }
}
```

[image]

This looks like `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["Tenant"]` is null during unit test run, how do I assign that value in `BaseController` from unit test?

Comment: Which MVC version are you using ? The best way is to inject Tenant from constructor so you can unit test easily. That's why DI are made for.

Comment: MVC 4, yes i'm already using DI in original source code. We assign Tenant based on requested url, a multi tenant kind of system.

Comment: Well, why can't you just set : System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["Tenant"] = new Tenant() when you initialize your test?

Comment: because by default HttpContext.Current is null in unit

Comment: @Abhimanyu Current controller tightly coupled to implementation concerns (`HttpContext`) that make it difficult to unit test it in isolation. Review current design and decouple from `HttpContext.Current`

Comment: can't we Moc HttpContext for now and assign Current.Items["Tenant"] ?

Comment: No. Also `Controller` already has a `HttpContext` property that tries to decouple by using `HttpContextBase`. That property can be accessed and set via the ControllerContext.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I have provided an answer explaining the problem along with a suggested solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current controller tightly coupled to implementation concerns (`HttpContext`) that make it difficult to unit test it in isolation.

Review current design and decouple from `HttpContext.Current` which is `null` as IIS is not available when unit testing.

Also `Controller` already has a `HttpContext` property

```
public HttpContextBase HttpContext { get; }
```

that tries to decouple by using `HttpContextBase` which able to be mocked.

That property can be accessed and set via the `ControllerContext`.

So first update the controller to use local `HttpContext` property

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
    public virtual Tenant Tenant {
        get { return HttpContext.Items["Tenant"] as Tenant; }
    }
}
```

Now that the controller is using a context that can be mocked, it can be unit tested as needed.

```
//Arrange
var tenant = new Tenant() {
    //...
};
var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>(); //USING MOQ
mockHttpContext.Setup(_ => _.Items["Tenant"]).Returns(tenant);

var controller = new DefaultController();
controller.ControllerContext = 
    new ControllerContext(mockHttpContext.Object, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData(), controller);

//Act
var result = controller.Index();

//Assert
//...
```

Comment: My bad. this looks great now, unit test satisfied. I am worried on converting HttpContext.Current.Items to HttpContext.Items, because I'm already using HttpContext.Current.Items everywhere including filters and .aspx pages. Also with BaseViewPage i.e. WebViewPage. Just changing this in BaseController does not break build but fingers crossed on performance implications.

Comment: @Abhimanyu it wont break the other as the one used in the controller is just a wrapper abstraction for `HttpContext.Current` to allow for better decoupling from static dependencies.

Comment: Should i try to convert rest HttpContext.Current.Items to HttpContext.Items in the project or just fine?

Comment: @Abhimanyu You really try to avoid tightly coupling to `HttpContext.Current` for the same reason you had problems trying to test. You can gradually refactor that over time and not make it a big issue now. The controller and controller context is accessible in most places.